# cannot delete my entity hibernate with many to many relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this class

```
public class User implements Serializable {

 @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL} )
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))

    private Collection<Role> rolesCollection = new ArrayList<>();
}

}
```

I am using this code to delete

```
  User user = userAPI.findUser(userName);
        user = userDao.merge(user);
        try {
            userDao.delete(user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but I still have the data in the database and I am not getting any exception.

I want to delete the user with its roles in the join table ... How can I do that ?

Comment: What is `userDao` ad what does `userDao.delete()` do? And why are you merging the user before deleting it?

Comment: You need to have a transaction, and it must commit. BTW, cascade=ALL on a ManyToMany is not a good idea at all. If two users A and B have the same role, you don't want to delete the role when deleting user A.

Comment: but I am deleting from the join table only

Comment: No. You're calling delete() on a user. So that deletes the user. And since there is a cascade= ALL on user.roles, the roles of the user will be deleted as well.

Comment: ok How can I solve this ? ... Actually it doesn't delete any thing!

Comment: I did merge before delete because I was getting detached entity error

Comment: Hibernate will automaticly delete user and proper records from relation table. The question is, what do you have in your `userDao.delete()` method. Provide code for that.

Comment: in delete I am calling remove :)